# ABI file not generated

Tags: eosio.cdt, abi, compilation, eosio-cpp, abigen

I have compiled a smart contract using `eosio-cpp -o addbook.wasm addbook.cpp --abigen` command.
Compilation was successfull and `wasm` file got generated. But I cant find abi.

eosio-cpp version is,

```
eosio-cpp -v 

clang version 7.0.0 (https://github.com/eosio/clang.git 6b886302a11a8419b76e469794ff9d0c531a4b4b) (https://github.com/eosio/llvm 9a9ff09d4302331d3289fdf58a64213506b4aefb)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.0/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: did u got the answer?

Comment: I have downgraded cdt version to 1.5

Comment: The name of class in x.cpp must be identified with the file name.show your source code.

Comment: those conditions are already satisfied @潘业达

Comment: Is this particularly with CDT 1.6.1? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't getting an abi file, but it was compiling fine.
I finally noticed that I had the file named: **widgets.cpp** but the class was **widget**. Watch out for missing "S"s.
Ran again and the abi file appeared.